# CMake add_subdirectory fails but okay when config is in main CMakeLists.txt

Tags: cmake

The following CMakeLists.txt builds and runs my executable Sandbox project fine:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.22)
project(Learning)

add_subdirectory(Engine)

add_executable(Sandbox Sandbox/src/Application.cpp)
target_link_libraries(Sandbox PUBLIC Engine)
```

But moving the `add_executable` and `target_link_libraries` calls for Sandbox into their own CMakeLists.txt and `add_subdirectory` fails:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.22)
project(Learning)

add_subdirectory(Engine)
add_subdirectory(Sandbox)
```

And:

```
add_executable(Sandbox Application.cpp)
target_link_libraries(Sandbox PUBLIC Engine)
```

The Engine CMakeLists.txt is:

```
add_library(Engine SHARED Test.h Test.cpp)
```

There is a CMakeLists.txt in each of the Engine and Sandbox directories that calls `add_subdirectory` for the relevant `src` folder.

Test.h in Engine exports the relevant symbols:

```
namespace Engine {
__declspec(dllexport) void Print();
}
```

Which is forward declared in Application.cpp in Sandbox:

```
namespace Engine {
__declspec(dllimport) void Print();
}
```

When running, I get the following output:

```
D:\Learning\cmake-build-debug\Sandbox\src\Sandbox.exe

Process finished with exit code -1073741515 (0xC0000135)
```

Why does moving this into it's own CMakeLists.txt cause the Sandbox process to finish with an exit code other than zero when run?

Comment: "cause the Sandbox process to finish with an exit code other than zero when built and run" - So, have you got the error when you **build** the project, or when you **run** it? Please, add the **error message** to the question post.

Comment: Added - I didn't think it relevant other than being a non-zero exit code.

Comment: The error code means that some **dll is not found** when you run your executable: https://www.google.com/search?q=Process+finished+with+exit+code+%220xC0000135%22+site:stackoverflow.com. Only those dlls can be found which are located in the same directory as the executable or which directories are listed in the `PATH` variable. You may instruct CMake to put created executables and shared libraries into specific directory by setting [CMAKE_RUNTIME_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/variable/CMAKE_RUNTIME_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY.html) variable.

Comment: Ah, okay. The dll needs to be accessible by the executable. That's the missing bit of information I hadn't clocked and which I need to tell CMake to make available. :+1: